# Don't understand USING syntax in MySQL

Tags: mysql

If i remove `USING (nid,sid)`, i get the column is ambigious error. I don't quite understand what `USING` does here? Is it joining the nid and sid returned from the subquery to the nid, sid in the outer select query?

```
 SELECT sid, nid, max_rating FROM outcomes
JOIN (SELECT nid, sid, MAX(rating) AS max_rating from outcomes group by nid, sid) AS newtable
USING (nid, sid)
WHERE rating = max_rating AND name LIKE '%test%'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, `USING` is being used to join the two tables using both `nid` and `sid`. But it has added advantages.

- First, your result will not have duplicate columns for `nid` and `sid`, as the `USING` statement merges the columns together.
- Second, if you would like to use `nid` or `sid` in your `WHERE` clause, you would not need to specify which table to use for that column, you could directly use something like `sid > 10`.

Comment: And please note that this is supported only in PostgreSQL and MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

The USING(column_list) clause names a list of columns that must exist in both tables. If tables a and b both contain columns c1, c2, and c3, the following join compares corresponding columns from the two tables:

```
a LEFT JOIN b USING (c1,c2,c3)
```

The above is taken from the documentation of MySQL. I hope that this is helpfull.